# Check Launch Uri when Application Starts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to check whether an app was navigated to from a secondary tile in `App.xaml.cs`? I need to somehow link a user to the WiFi launch uri from a secondary tile on the start screen without the user navigating to the MainPage first. I'd like to check in either `Application_Launching` or `Application_Activated`. Currently I am doing this in the `OnNavigatedTo` event in MainPage which is displaying the MainPage before the built in WiFi app, and this is confusing as well as annoying for the user.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
//From Pinned Tile
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey(Constants.Key))
        {
            string _title = null;
            _title = NavigationContext.QueryString[Constants.Key];

            if (_title != null)
            {
                switch (_title)
                {
                    case "Tile_WiFi":
                        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-wifi:"));
                        break;

                NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove(Constants.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not able to use `NavigationService` or `NavigationContext` within App.xaml.cs. Is there an alternative? To note, I got this idea from other apps performing this function on the Store and they do not have the issue of navigating to the MainPage first before the built in app.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if we are to navigate to WiFi here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Secondary tiles can have a navigation URI that points directly to a page, and that page will be navigated to directly when the user taps the secondary tile.

If you do not want to show any page, but launch another app you can try to handle the RootFrame.Navigating event, then check the uri and query of the NavigatingCancelEventArgs parameter and cancel the navigation.

Comment: Yes I am currently navigating to MainPage and handling the QueryString value from the secondary tile. The question is how to avoid showing the MainPage to the user before the user is redirected to the built in WiFi app?

Comment: How do you set the secondary tile? I am using ShellTile.Create(uri, tileData, true); and as the first parameter I can pass the path to a page in my app

Comment: I am creating my tile that way as well.  RootFrame is a good idea for navigating, but I don't need to Navigate to a new page, just capture the QueryString value from the tile and then use the built in launch uri `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-wifi:"))` to launch the built in app.